# Javascript; nested for-loop not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
var divs = [];
for (var x = 0; x <= nodeArray.length; x++) {
    for (var q = 0; q <= nodeArray.childElementCount; q++) {
        divs[x][q] = nodeArray[x].childNodes[q].childNodes[0]  
    };
};
```

I need a two dimensional array of the child of every child of a div for multiple divs.
Can't get it to work ;c
Anyone knows if this is even possible with javascript?

Thanks.

Edit:

Thanks guys, it works now! :D
I ended up doing it like this:

```
    var divs = [];
    nodeArray.forEach(function(array, index) {
        divs[index] = nodeArray[index].children;
    });

    var imgs = [];
    for (var x = 0; x < divs.length; x++) {
        imgs[x] = [];
        for (var y = 0; y < divs[x].length; y++) {
            imgs[x][y] = divs[x][y].childNodes[0];
        }
    }
```

Using your feedback it works now! Really really really thanks! ;D

Comment: Ofcourse this is possible. But you have to set `divs[x] = [];` in the loop as well, since you're trying to push to non-existant arrays. `divs[x]` doesn't exist if you don't create it, so `divs[x][q]` can't exists either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Arrays are 0-indexed, This means that the last element of an array is not at `array.length` but at `array.length - 1`.
2. You'll have to create a new array (sub-array) and then start adding elements to it.

Your code should be like this:

```
var divs = [];
for (var x = 0; x < nodeArray.length; x++) {
//          here ^^^
    divs[x] = []; // create a new sub-array (or divs.push([]);)
    for (var q = 0; q < nodeArray.childElementCount; q++) {
    //          here ^^^
        divs[x][q] = nodeArray[x].childNodes[q].childNodes[0];
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var divs = [];
for (var x = 0; x <= nodeArray.length; x++) {
    divs[x] = [];

    for (var q = 0; q <= nodeArray[x].length; q++) {
        divs[x][q] = nodeArray[x][q][0];
    };
};
```